# Questions on the Related/Linked Sidebar do not indicate if an accepted answer exists

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, related-questions, linked-questions

[image: shows math.se is working and this kinda a bump lel super old bump]

From here, notice how the sidebars for these three sites are a tad different, notably, Math.SE.  I'm not sure if it's just me, but Math.SE clearly shows whether or not a question has been accepted or not in the sidebar.

I decided to have a gander at the other sites, because I wasn't sure if it was just a bug that wasn't properly affecting Arqade or StackOverflow. These are the sites I noticed **don't** have the questions in the sidebar properly "marked":

---

**Linked sidebar:**

- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38437/do-gemstones-have-a-purpose-in-skyrim)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)
- [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24750/how-do-you-quote-a-passage-that-has-used-sic-mistakenly)
- [TravelAnswers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/how-to-avoid-drinking-vodka)
- [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/545/how-do-i-debug-drupal)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/implications-of-samoa-skipping-a-friday)

**Related sidebar:**

- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38437/do-gemstones-have-a-purpose-in-skyrim)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)
- [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24750/how-do-you-quote-a-passage-that-has-used-sic-mistakenly)
- [TravelAnswers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/how-to-avoid-drinking-vodka)
- [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/545/how-do-i-debug-drupal)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/implications-of-samoa-skipping-a-friday)

---

**Sites that do reflect if questions are answered or not** (*in sidebar*):

- [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199676/what-are-imaginary-numbers)
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159637/what-is-the-mars-curiosity-rovers-software-built-in)

---

I'll update this list as I find more, but can this be fixed?

Comment: Programmers looks the same as Math.SE

Comment: Thanks, I'll update it, @mat, could you also tell me if you can see any "accepted answers" questions with the links I provided? I really don't want to have this be a problem only on my end

Comment: I see the same thing as you do. Reasonable request too, I think.

Comment: UX.SE indicates [lack of] an accepted answer. But only just. (It's hard to tell which style is which...)

Comment: umm.. did you take a look? It's fixed now, as part of some past redesign. You just wasted 100 rep.

Comment: I imagine this got fixed some time ago during consolidation of styles to make the sites more consistent and easier to maintain. Does this occur on any sites for you now?

Answer (score 8):

Stack Overflow (and the other sites that don't have the questions with accepted answers marked) are just missing a bit of CSS that the other sites have:

```
.answered-accepted {
    background-color: #D2EAC1 !important;
}
```

Or, if you're a purist who is offended by the use of `!important`:

```
.show-votes .sidebar-related .answered-accepted {
    background-color: #D2EAC1;
}
```

All of the plumbing is already there in the generated HTML, there's just no styles provided to differentiate it for display purposes.

Presumably, this feature was introduced with the new custom-designed themes for the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites, but never got back-ported to Stack Overflow's crusty old design.

Comment: So will this get implemented soon? Or will we have to wait

Comment: You'll have to wait for someone on the Stack Exchange team to respond.

Comment: Ah, okay, hopefully this gets the attention of someone higher up, thanks!

Comment: @disregard Look for the [start bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) button. Pinging me about it doesn't do any good, Stack Exchange hasn't hired me in the meantime. And if they did, it wouldn't be as a front-end UI designer. :-)

Comment: eww specificity